# GWT CellBrowser- how to always show all values?

Tags: gwt, cellbrowser

GWT's [CellBrowser](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#cellbrowser) is a great way of presenting dynamic data.

However when the browser contains more rows than some (seemingly) arbitrary maximum, it offers a "Show More" label that the user can click to fetch the unseen rows.

How can I disable this behavior, and force it to always show every row?

[image]

Comment: Good question. `CellBrowser.createDisplay(...)` calls `new BrowserCellList<C>(...)`. And that uses `CellList.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE`, which is fixed to 25. Not a very configurable piece of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of getting rid of the "Show More" (which you can combine):

- In your `TreeViewModel`, in your `NodeInfo`'s `setDisplay` or in the `DataProvider` your give to the `DefaultNodeInfo`, in `onRangeChange`: overwrite the display's visible range to the size of your data.
- Extend `CellBrowser` and override its `createPager` method to return `null`. It won't change the list's page size though, but you can set it to some very high value there too.

Answer (score 2):

The below CellBrowser removes the "Show More" text plus loads all available elements without paging.

```java
public class ShowAllElementsCellBrowser extends CellBrowser {

    public ShowAllElementsCellBrowser(TreeViewModel viewModel, CellBrowser.Resources resources) {
        super(viewModel, null, resources);
    }

    @Override
    protected <C> Widget createPager(HasData<C> display) {
        PageSizePager pager = new PageSizePager(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // removes the text "Show More" during loading
        display.setRowCount(0);

        // increase the visible range so that no one ever needs to page
        display.setVisibleRange(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        pager.setDisplay(display);

        return pager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a valid and simple solution in setting page size to the CellBrowser's builder.
Hope this will help.

`CellBrowser.Builder<AClass> cellBuilder = new CellBrowser.Builder<AClass>(myModel, null);
cellBuilder.pageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
cellBrowser = cellBuilder.build();`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using the:

```html
cellTree.setDefaultNodeSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

method on your Cell Tree. You must do this before you begin expanding the tree.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to navigate through elements of `treeview` dom to get "show more" element with

```
public static List<Element> findElements(Element element) {
    ArrayList<Element> result = new ArrayList<Element>();
    findShowMore(result, element);  return result; }

private static void findShowMore(ArrayList res, Element element) {
    String c;

    if (element == null) {      return;     }

    if (element.getInnerText().equals("Show more")) {       res.add(element);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DOM.getChildCount(element); i++) {      Element
child = DOM.getChild(element, i);       findShowMore(res, child);   } }
```

and than use:

```
if (show) {   element.getStyle().clearDisplay(); } else {  
element.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE); }
```